# I have rollback wrong migration file how to fixed it

Tags: laravel, routes, migration

Rolling back: 2022_01_19_091029_create_update_meet__table
Rolled back:  2022_01_19_091029_create_update_meet__table (10.23ms)
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolerp> php artisan migrate

Migrating: 2022_01_19_091029_create_update_meet__table

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2029' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: INSERT INTO `master_module_infos` (`id`, `module_id`, `parent_id`, `type`, `is_saas`, `name`, `route`, `lang_name`, `icon_class`, `active_status`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `school_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES

```
    (2029, 28, 0, '1', 0,'Google Meet','','google_meet','flaticon-reading', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),

    (2030, 28, 2029, '2', 0,'Class Meeeting','meet-class-meeting','meet_class_meeting','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
    (2031, 28, 2030, '3', 0,'Add','','','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
    (2032, 28, 2030, '3', 0,'Edit','','','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
    (2033, 28, 2030, '3', 0,'Delete','','','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
    (2034, 28, 2030, '3', 0,'Start Class','','','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),

    (2035, 28, 2029, '2', 0,'Staff Meeting','meet-staff-meetings','meet_staff_meeting','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
    (2036, 28, 2035, '3', 0,'Add','','','', 1, 1, 1, 1, '2019-07-25 02:21:21', '2019-07-25 04:24:22'),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think Id is unique. Kindly check table id of 2029 is created or not.